# ASP.NET Adding data from stored procedure into custom table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

My problem is essentially this:

I have a connection to a SQL-Server database. I have a class that can access this database and return a DataTable.

I want to use the DataTable gotten from the stored procedure to generate a bootstrap table in my HTML.

Essentially, I want to end up with something like:

```
Dim table as DataTable //(let's say this already has all the data I need.)

Dim returnString as String = "<table class=""table table-striped"">"
returnString = "<thead><tr>"
for i = 0 to DataTable.Columns.count - 1
    returnString = returnString + "<th>" + DataTable.columns(i).HeaderText + "</th>"
Next
returnString = returnString + "</thead><tbody>"
for i = 0 to DataTable.rows.count - 1
    returnString = returnString + "<tr>"
    for j = 0 to DataTable.columns.count - 1
        returnString = returnString + "<td>" + DataTable.rows(i)(j).value.ToString() + "</td>"
    Next
    returnString = returnString + "</tr>"
Next

returnString = returnString + "</tbody></table>"
```

I know I'm doing more work than I need to. But I'm not sure how to do this in ASP.NET (I've never worked in this environment before), so I'm at a bit of a loss. How do I insert my "returnString" variable into the markup? I think seeing how to do this would help me really generally with understanding ASP.NET architecture.

Comment: This would be an ideal job for the repeater control - but if you have your table set up in the string bind the returnString to the value of a literal control on the aspx page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're writing this code in the code behind page of your aspx page, you'd want to place a [Literal control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your aspx page, build your string as above and set the Text property of the literal control to your generated text.

However, if you are just getting started with asp.net and your environment allows, I highly suggest you look into asp.net MVC, as razor syntax is much more friendly to generating Bootstrap content.

Comment: Thank you for the point in the right direction. Started an MVC tutorial and it looks like it'll be way easier for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Like DavidB said you can use a repeater like so:

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Listing">
    <tr class="Header">
        <td>
            Rebate Run #
        </td>
        <td>
            Run Date
        </td>
        <td>
            Transaction
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            Frames Amount
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            Cash Amount
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptRemittance" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="Detail">
                <td align="center">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RebatePaymentRunID")%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%# FormatDate(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PaymentRunDate"))%>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Transactions")%>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    R<%# FormatNumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FramesAmount"), 2)%>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    R<%# FormatNumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CashAmount"), 2)%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadLink" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RebatePaymentRunID") %>'>
                        <img src="../../images/icons/pdf.gif" alt="Download invoice"/>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

You can then bind your data source like this:

```
rptRemittance.DataSource = obj
rptRemittance.DataBind()
```